# Firebase reglas de seguridad para registrar un usuario

Tags: firebase, seguridad

estoy haciendo una aplicación donde tengo varias colecciones, de tal manera que para acceder a ciertas colecciones los usuarios deben de estar registrados, pero tengo que tener una colección denominada user, donde se tienen que ir guardando los datos de los usuarios que se registran (nombre y contraseña), adjunto foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahora trabajaba con las reglas generales de permitir acceso y escritura a todo el mundo, ahora quiero implementar la aplicación y no sé muy bien como dar acceso a los usuarios que se quieren registrar, porque me da un error, yo lo tengo implementado de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De tal manera que solo los usuarios registrados puedan acceder a las colecciones de 'meet' y 'sms', pero no consigo que me funcione para que un usuario nuevo pueda registrarse.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona exactamente y qué error da? ¿Revisaste [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)?

Comment: Perdona que soy nueva en esto, sencillamente desde que cambié las reglas de acceso, si intento registrarme desde la aplicación no me deja

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te sirva, esta regla yo la implemento, pero yo en vez del correo como tú lo tienes en el documento, tengo uid y lo comparo con **request.auth.uid**, pero te deje comparándose con el correo, trata que las colecciones sean en plural ejemplo en vez user coloca users

```
match /user/{userEmail} {
      allow read;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.email == userEmail;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
```

Comment: Va perfecto, muchísimas gracias. Tomo nota en cuanto a la nomenclatura de las colecciones. Gracias